# Adding Items on 2 tables in MYSQL database inside pipeline using Scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I am trying to add 2 tables in my MYSQL database I successfully added the 2 tables but the separated items like itemA and itemB is not added on Database

If I remove the itemB, ItemA works fine and added on table1, if 2 tables I always got this error

"NameError: name 'items_f21' is not defined"
Any Idea please?

Here's my code

sales_item_spider.py

```
    def parse_1(self, response):

    item = GpdealsSpiderItem_hm()

    for product_item_hm in response.css('li.product-item'):

        hm_title = product_item_hm.css('h3.item-heading a.link::text').extract_first()
        hm_regular_price = product_item_hm.css('strong.item-price span.price.regular::text').extract_first()
        hm_sale_price = product_item_hm.css('strong.item-price span.price.sale::text').extract_first()
        hm_photo_url = product_item_hm.css('.image-container img::attr(data-src)').extract_first()
        hm_description_url = product_item_hm.css('h3.item-heading a::attr(href)').extract_first()

        item['hm_title'] = hm_title 
        item['hm_regular_price'] = hm_regular_price 
        item['hm_sale_price'] = hm_sale_price 
        item['hm_photo_url'] = hm_photo_url 
        item['hm_description_url'] = hm_description_url 

        yield item

def parse_2(self, response):

    items_f21 = GpdealsSpiderItem_f21()

    for product_item_forever in response.css('div.pi_container'):

        f21_title = product_item_forever.css('p.p_name::text').extract_first()
        f21_regular_price = product_item_forever.css('span.p_old_price::text').extract_first()
        f21_sale_price = product_item_forever.css('span.p_sale.t_pink::text').extract_first()
        f21_photo_url = product_item_forever.css('img::attr(data-original)').extract_first()
        f21_description_url = product_item_forever.css('a.item_slider.product_link::attr(href)').extract_first()

        items_f21['f21_title'] = f21_title 
        items_f21['f21_regular_price'] = f21_regular_price 
        items_f21['f21_sale_price'] = f21_sale_price 
        items_f21['f21_photo_url'] = f21_photo_url 
        items_f21['f21_description_url'] = f21_description_url 

        yield items_f21
```

pipelines.py

```
def create_table(self):
    self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS saleitems_hm""")
    self.curr.execute("""create table saleitems_hm(
                    hm_title text,
                    hm_regular_price text,
                    hm_sale_price text,
                    hm_photo_url text,
                    hm_description_url text
                    )""")

    self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS saleitems_f21""")
    self.curr.execute("""create table saleitems_f21(
                    f21_title text,
                    f21_regular_price text,
                    f21_sale_price text,
                    f21_photo_url text,
                    f21_description_url text
                    )""")

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.store_db(item)
    return item

def store_db(self, item):
    self.curr.execute("""insert into saleitems_hm values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
            item['hm_title'],
            item['hm_regular_price'],
            item['hm_sale_price'],
            item['hm_photo_url'],
            item['hm_description_url']
        ))
    self.conn.commit()

    self.curr.execute("""insert into saleitems_f21 values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
            items_f21['f21_title'],
            items_f21['f21_regular_price'],
            items_f21['f21_sale_price'],
            items_f21['f21_photo_url'],
            items_f21['f21_description_url']
        ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `store_db` uses a `items_f21` variable, which is never defined before.

On `store_db` you should use only the `item` variable, and use the corresponding `INSERT` statement depending on the type of item it is:

```py
def store_db(self, item):
    if isinstance(item, GpdealsSpiderItem_hm):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into saleitems_hm values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
                item['hm_title'],
                item['hm_regular_price'],
                item['hm_sale_price'],
                item['hm_photo_url'],
                item['hm_description_url']
            ))
    else:
        self.curr.execute("""insert into saleitems_f21 values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
                item['f21_title'],
                item['f21_regular_price'],
                item['f21_sale_price'],
                item['f21_photo_url'],
                item['f21_description_url']
            ))
    self.conn.commit()
```